# Add twitter bootstrap to current project

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am thinking on adding some elements from twitter bootstrap to my current web application. This would help me to be more effective in some parts of the web development process. I do consider my self good at css and I have always built my sites from the ground up.

Is it viable to use some parts of twitter bootstrap, like the grid system? And then use my own custom classes for styling etc? Or should you go all out and use every aspect of bootstrap, and customize the bootstrap classes?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case, you want to have bare minimal code that's necessary for your styling and you are comfortable in extending/ re-integrating as and when need arises in future then can use those particular bootstrap parts which you want and can style them as you want and can leave the unwanted bootstrap features..

But if you don't mind some extra code, that may add to your page load time, then you can go for the whole of the bootstrap.

In either of the cases, it would be better to leave the core bootstrap code unaltered and write your own code for added/modified functionality. This will give you the option of using the bootstrap styling in case if need arises in future and also you can straight-away update bootstrap files when updated versions arrive..